# Twilio Robotic Voice

Tags: android, twilio

I´m experiencing some issues when I make a call through VoIp with the `Twilio Voice SDK beta-6`. Im getting robotic voices in low-end devices when we are in a call (**BQ A4.5**). But when we Call each other via nice Android Smartphones (like **Samsung Galaxy S7**) we are not getting any "robotic" voice Stream.

Any clues of why this  is happening?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you should ask twilio support, because they are now planning to release stable release.

Comment: I'm a developer evangelist at Twilio and I also recommend you [contact support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) about this. I don't think this is something that can be solved over SO.